# Haskell- creating 2d array

Tags: haskell, multidimensional-array

I am fairly new to Haskell and trying to improve myself as far as functional languages are concerned. I am attempting to create a function that will take a number of rows and columns and produce a 2D array as follows, for example:

```
 arrayMaker :: (Int, Int) -> [[Int]]
  -- use replicate function somehow to create each row?
```

The resulting matrix would appear as follows (for 5 rows, 3 columns):

```
 [[14, 15, 16],
 [13, 12, 11],
 [8, 9, 10],
 [7, 6, 5],
 [2, 3, 4]]
```

Notice the values begin in the last row at 2. Also the array should alternate between ascending and descending rows. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Write a function `row` that given `i` generates the i-th row. Then `map row [1..numRows]`. To do that, can you write a simple arithmetical formula for the number in position `(i,j)` when `i` is even? and when `i` is odd?

Comment: Note that [Int] in haskell is not an array but a list. In practice you typically would not want to use lists to represent a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with this example:

```
rowMaker1 n k = [ n .. n+k-1 ] : rowMaker1 (n+k) k
```

`rowMaker1` creates groups of consecutive numbers. It creates an infinite list, so we use `take` to limit the number of elements computed:

```
ghci> take 5 (rowMaker1 1 3)
[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14,15] ]
```

We can also create a descending version:

```
rowMaker2 n k = [ n,n-1..n-k+1 ] : rowMaker2 (n-k) k

ghci> take 5 (rowMaker2 16 3)
[[16,15,14],[13,12,11],[10,9,8],[7,6,5],[4,3,2]]
```

The goal will be to define `arrayMaker` like this:

```
arrayMaker (nrows,ncols) = take nrows (rowMaker start ncols)
  where start = ???
        rowMaker n k = ???
```

We just need a `rowMaker` which will alternate between ascending and descending groups.

Does this help?

If you get stuck, here's one possibility for the `rowMaker` function:

> rowMaker n k = [ n .. n+k-1 ] : rowMaker2 (n-k) k
>     rowMaker2 n k = [ n, n-1 .. n-k+1 ] : rowMaker (n-k-k+1) k

and you can run this code here: http://tpcg.io/_YJENGK

Comment: sort of. Not sure how to tie rowMaker in to rowMaker1 and rowMaker2

Comment: How about having `rowMaker` create two groups - an ascending group and then a descending group - and then repeat by calling itself.

Comment: How would you do this? I am terrible with recursion and that is a large reason of starting Haskell. However, I've been having trouble finding examples pertaining to what I am working with

Comment: It will have the form: `rowMaker n k = (formula for asc group) : (formula for desc group) : rowMaker new-n k` - the colon operator is the basic way to create lists. `a:b:c` prepends the elements `a` and `b` to the front of list `c`.

Comment: The link to lpaste.net 404s now. @ErikR are you able to fix the link or incorporate something like its contents into the text of the answer?

Comment: @JimWitschey Ok - replaced the lpaste link with a spoiler block